# Counting How many Columns of a 2d array in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

how do you count the columns of an array in PHP?

this is the structure of the dB

[image: structure]

Ive used an api factory to get my data from the db

($ratings is from the Controller)

```
@if(!empty($ratings['result'] ) && count($ratings['result'] ))
    @foreach($ratings['result'] as $val)
```

I've counted how many Reviews by using this code

```
$count = count($ratings['result']);
echo $count;
```

Now I wanted to count how many elements of customerId array.

Please help.

Comment: Which `customerid` or do you mean all the customerid's which are subordinate to the `like` / `dislike` etc etc

Comment: all the customersid's subordinates

Comment: either a loop or individually doing something like `count($ratings['result']->likes['customerId)`

Comment: I got this error

Trying to get property 'likes' of non-object 

i also tried

count($ratings['result']['customerId']->likes);
but got this error 
Undefined index: customerId

and 

$count = count($ratings['result']->customerId);

and got error Trying to get property 'customerId' of non-object

does it mean the data is not existing?

Comment: likes is not a object , you can get like this count( $ratings['result']['likes']['customerId'] )

Comment: If you do a sample dump of $ratings result, and your expected output/result.  This could be easier to follow.  `var_export($ratings['result']);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function countCustomerIdLikes($rating=array()) {
    if ( is_array($rating) && array_key_exists('likes', $rating) && array_key_exists('customerId', $rating['likes'])) { 
        return count( $rating['likes']['customerId'] );
    }
    return 0;
}

$count = countCustomerIdLikes($ratings['result']);
```